# how to upload file in linux machine using seleniumgrid

Tags: linux, junit, image-uploading, selenium-grid

I had this piece of code:

```
Element.sendKeys(By.xpath("//input[@id='documentUploadT7Form:documentFileUpload:file']"),
        "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg", driver, new WebDriverWait(driver, 60L));
```

in selenium WC running fine. When we have changed to "seleniumgrid and Linux" file does not upload any more.

Would you suggest how to upload a file in Linux by using selenium grid?

Answer (score 0):

The path you are using is wrong for Linux. You would need to store the Koala.jpg file in the linux RC machine and provide that path in the command.

```
"C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg"
```